# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "USER" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to make a trigger, it compiles but with 2 errors (same error different location). This is the trigger, I have the table and sequence created

```
create or replace TRIGGER BIU_APPLICATION
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON APPLICATION
REFERENCING FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF inserting THEN IF :new.APPLICATION_ID IS NULL THEN
SELECT APPLICATION_ID_SEQ.nextval
INTO :new.APPLICATION_ID
FROM dual;
END IF;
:new.created_by := NVL(apex_application.g_user USER);
:new.created_dt := SYSDATE;
END IF;
IF inserting OR updating THEN
:new.created_by := NVL(apex_application.g_user USER);
:new.created_dt := SYSDATE;
END IF;
END;
```

The error I get is

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "USER" when expecting one of the following:     . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or default    like like2 like4 likec as between from using || multiset    member submultiset The symbol "." was substituted for "USER" to continue.

Comment: Different arguments to functions are separated by commas. You didn't put a comma between the two arguments of `nvl()`.

Comment: If you are going to use a sequence to populate a column (APPLICATION_ID), then you need to use it _every_ time.  Allowing a user/processs to supply the value _some_ time, and relying on the sequence only when they don't  is a recipe for disaster.  At the very least, you run a very high risk of pulling a sequence that matches a value previously supplied by the user ....

Comment: The APPLICATION_ID will always be populated by default on new entry, it isn’t something manually inputted by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about "," in  NVL:

```
 NVL(apex_application.g_user, USER);
```

note: you don't need select sequence.nextval by SQL. You can do this like:

```
:new.APPLICATION_ID :=  APPLICATION_ID_SEQ.nextval
```

Comment: Ah man all this time it was a comma I never noticed... Thanks man

Comment: _Ah man all this time it was a comma I never noticed... Thanks man"_   Back in the mid-80's I once observed an entire team of IBM engineers spend two weeks trying to track a problem that eventually led back to a missing comma.